# I want fetch data from second table if not present in first table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, magento

I have a **products table** which has a price(General Price) column. I have a second **product_price table** with product_id, company_id and price(Company Specific Product Price).

The idea is to set and display different product prices for different companies and if the price is not set for the selected company in product_price table, it should fetch the general price from products table.

I tried using left join. But, didn't get a desired result

```
SELECT 
    products.id, products.price, product_price.price
FROM
    products
        LEFT JOIN
    product_price ON products.id = product_price.product_id
        AND company_id = $id
```

Comment: its easyer if you use eloquent i think with an if statment.if the returned value is null from the first result than the other (another if $thing ==null) will be executed which will fetch data from second table , i dont know if this is what you want exactly but this is how i approach such problemes

Comment: I want to reduce the processing time here, as there will be huge no. of products. I will prefer creating a view and accessing the data from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    products.id, 
    COALESCE(product_price.price,products.price)
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN product_price 
ON products.id = product_price.product_id
   AND company_id = $id
```